# ActiveRecord Association without Foreign Key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I am trying to build a relationship model between users. A user can either initiate a relation, or receive a relation from another user. Therefore, the relations table in the db has the foreign keys "initiator_id" and "recipient_id".
Now, I can figure what relations the user initiated or received using the following associations:

```
has_many :initiated_relations, :foreign_key => :initiator_id, :class_name => 'Relation', :dependent => :destroy
has_many :received_relations,  :foreign_key => :recipient_id, :class_name => 'Relation', :dependent => :destroy
```

What I am trying to do, is build an association that will fetch me all relations that belong to a user (either initiated or received). Trying the following does not work, and complains about the lack of "user_id" field:

```
has_many :relations, :conditions => 'recipient_id = #{id} or initiator_id = #{id}'
```

How can I create an association that is solely based on the conditions field, without looking for the default foreign_key? Or is there perhaps a completely different approach to solving this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I can think of using `finder_sql` for that:

```
has_many :relations, :finder_sql => 'select * from relations right outer join users
    on relations.recipient_id = #{id} or relations.initiator_id = #{id}'
```

Apart from that, you can just write a method that will return a united array of the two relations associations', but you will lose the advantage of an association interface (phew).

Perhaps someone will come up with a better solution.

Comment: I already tried using finder_sql, however if there is any other way to achieve this I would prefer that, because with finder_sql I lose all functionality of associations. e.g: I can't do `user.relations.find(:all, :conditions => {:confirmed => true})` or any other such function. Thanx for your input though, much appreciated.

Comment: i don't think this works.  #{id} is evaluated at the class level, not the instance.  it would need to be a proc, which as of rails v3.2.13 is only supported on :conditions option.  Rails 4 will be much better for this stuff.

Comment: `:finder_sql` has been deprecated and been removed from Rails 4.1. So this solution doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 9):

From your comments to @neutrino's answer I understand, that you only need this "relation" for read only operations. If you're on Rails 3 you can utilize the fact, that it uses lazy fetching. The `where()` method returns `ActiveRecord::Relation` object, which you can later modify. So you can define a method like this:

```
def User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def all_relations
    Relation.where("initiator_id => ? OR recipient_id = ?", id, id)
  end
end
```

And then you can do:

```
User.all_relations.where(:confirmed => true).all
```

Comment: This seems like a very elegant solution, and yes, I only want this relation for read-only purposes. However, I am not using Rails 3, so this won't work for me :(. +1 for the great answer though :).

Comment: Scopes are great but you can't eager-load them